# How to get the number of new commits added to the local repository by a git pull?

Tags: git, commit

When I run `git pull`, I'd like to know how many commits the `pull` added to my local repository, preferably on the current branch only. Is there a way to get this information ?

The manual for `git-pull` doesn't seem to indicate anything about this, and I haven't found any thread online specifically dealing with this.

Comment: `git pull` is a shortcut for two commands `git fetch` and `git merge`. `git fetch` will get all commits from a remote, not just for one branch

Comment: So just fetch, then status will tell you the delta between your local and remote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing on @Grzegorz' answer, but with a complete substitute for `git pull` and more appropriate answer to my question (requesting only the number of new commits), here is the command I came up with:

```
git fetch ; git status -bsu no ; git merge
```

Which will output something like this:

```
## master...origin/master [behind 6]
Updating 050a8c7..b8a6c2e
Fast-forward
 2.4/debian-10/Dockerfile | 2 +-
 2.5/debian-10/Dockerfile | 2 +-
 2.6/debian-10/Dockerfile | 2 +-
 README.md                | 6 +++---
 4 files changed, 6 insertions(+), 6 deletions(-)
```

giving you the number of new commits in the text between brackets `[behind 6]` meaning 6 new commits have been pulled to the current branch from the remote.

PS: Of course, if you `git pull --rebase` by default, you would have to change `git merge` with `git rebase`.

Answer (score 0):

Git pull doesn't give you that information.

But what you can do is:

`git fetch`
`git status`

```
On branch master
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 11 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
```

And this will give you information about how many commits will be pulled.